# MvcSiteMapProvider Installation Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nuget, razor-2, mvcsitemapprovider

I got this error while installing the sitemapprovider for mvc:

```
Install-Package : Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.2' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 2.0.20505.0' failed. Unable to find versions of 
'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc' that are compatible with 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 2.0.20505.0'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error indicates you are installing the [MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4 NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4/), but your project is MVC 5 (because it has Razor 3.2.2). You must install the package that matches your version of MVC (in this case, [MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5/)) into your project.

```
PM> Install-Package MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5
```

Do note that the [MvcSiteMapProvider NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcSiteMapProvider/) is obsolete and should not be installed into any project unless you intend to use MvcSiteMapProvider v3.x.

If you are upgrading from MvcSiteMapProvider v3 to v4, please see the [upgrade guide](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Upgrading-from-v3-to-v4).

Comment: You said it is obsolete, which one should I use?

Comment: Use the package that matches your MVC version (MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5 in your case).

Comment: Nuget is saying the MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5 package cannot be found.

Comment: The package is definitely online at NuGet. Sometimes Visual Studio is temperamental - try restarting it. Also, if you are in East Asia, there was a fiber optic cable outage today that could be interfering with your connectivity: http://tech.thaivisa.com/broken-undersea-aag-cable-slows-internet-across-southeast-asia/?utm_source=newsletter-20150107-1437&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=news